# quickfix library questions

Tags: finance, quickfix, fix-protocol

I’m new with the quickfix stuff and I have several questions regarding the quickfix library, and I will be more than happy to get answers from you:

I’m planning to develop FIX server that gets FIX request from multiple clients concurrently. Regarding that,

a)      What is the exact meaning of TargetID (i.e. CLIENT1) if I need to distinguish request from different clients (how can I distinguish those request from each other)?

b)      What in general is the meaning of TargetID regarding the server/client?

c)      How do I add custom fields and custom messages and what is the exact connection to message cracker object ?

Regards,

Mordechai Yaakobi

Comment: for adding custom messages and fields follow these simple steps http://adding-custom-fields-messages-in-qf-6-easy-steps.32054.n6.nabble.com

Answer (score 8):

1. `TargetID` is the NAME of the box
   to where you sending message, if
   you need to distinguish sessions
   for multiple clients (I assume into
   one server) just give each client
   different `SenderCompID`.

   On your server you have to setup one session for each client.

   Example for one server-client session:

   On your server (INCA):

   ```
   [SESSION]
   BeginString=FIX.4.0
   SenderCompID=INCA
   TargetCompID=CLIENT1
   ```

   On your client (CLIENT1):

   ```
   [SESSION]
   BeginString=FIX.4.0
   SenderCompID=CLIENT1
   TargetCompID=INCA
   ```

   quickfixengine distinguishes session
   (server-client connection) based on
   those 3 values: `(BeginString,
   TargetCompID, SenderCompID)`

   When you send message you put your
   comp id as `sendercompid` and the
   target to where you sending message
   as `targetcompid`. You specify
   `beginstring` based on the fix
   version you wish to use to
   communicate (`FIX4.0`/`FIX4.2`
   ....).
2. I guess it's explained above,
   TargetID is the ID of box where you
   sending messages. When server
   responding back to client it will
   set `SenderCompID` as it's (server)
   id and `TargetCompID` will be set to
   the client to where the response is
   being sent.
3. Custom fields depends on what
   exactly is required. FIX protocol
   specifies custom fields those with
   FieldID bigger than the reserved
   range, so your custom fields can
   start with FieldID 5000.

   There are couple of options about
   how to go about it. The simplest one
   is to just use the numerical value
   of message and add it to message (I
   assume you use c++ but it's similar
   with other languages).

   Something like:

   ```
    msg.setField(5000,"SomeValue");
   ```

   This custom field will not be
   validated automatically because FIX
   does not know about it. FIX uses xml
   files where each message and field
   is specified.

   There is a proper procedure to add a
   new message to xml specs and then
   regenerate quickfixengine code to
   generate new field structures but so
   far I did not need to do it.

   message cracker is just a method
   that takes pointer to generic
   message and then it looks at the
   message id (if I remember) and calls
   appropriate handler.

   It is one big if statement with lots
   of string operations so sometimes
   it's better to do the checking
   yourself, but you should be okay to
   use it.

   This is how the method looks like, you'll get the idea:

   ```
   void crack( const Message& message, 
         const FIX::SessionID& sessionID )
   {
   const std::string& msgTypeValue 
            = message.getHeader().getField( FIX::FIELD::MsgType );        
   if( msgTypeValue == "0" )
     onMessage( (const Heartbeat&)message, sessionID );
   else
   if( msgTypeValue == "A" )
     onMessage( (const Logon&)message, sessionID );
   else
   if( msgTypeValue == "1" )
     onMessage( (const TestRequest&)message, sessionID );
   else
   ```

   You then generally implement the
   appropriate method like for example
   if you only care about
   `ExecutionReport`s you implement in
   your code:

   ```
   virtual void onMessage( ExecutionReport&, const FIX::SessionID& );
   ```

   Then your application will get the
   `ExecutionReport` so that you can
   process it. The `onMessage` methods
   for messages that you don't
   implement simply do nothing and
   return so message will never get to
   your application.

If you need to add custom messages/fields I've found [this useful](http://old.nabble.com/Custom-Messages-Classes-Tutorial-td13495584.html), I haven't used it though.